# Prove injectivity and sujectivity $f: ℤ$ x $ℤ$ -> {$n ∈ ℤ : 4 | n$} , $f((x,y)) = 12x - 8y$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am really struggling when proving injectivity and surjectivity for mult variable function. Please if someone can guide the way.

Comment: The question is still unclear. What's the meaning of $n$?

Comment: @OliverJones I think n is just 12x - 8y, what ever they produce will be divisible by 4

Comment: for surjectivity: $f((n/4,n/4))=n$. for injectivity: can you see what surface the graph of $f$ defines, if its domain is $\mathbb R ^2$?

Comment: I see what you mean. You should write the range as $4\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ForeverMozart i can prove surjectivity by simply substituting? No this appeared on a algebra assignment, I have zero back knowledge of multivariable functions

Comment: @MingChao Of course!

Comment: For injectivity : $f(0,0)=f(2,3)$

Comment: @stity oh so its NOT injective :)

Comment: But it is injective if you fix one coordinate and let the other vary.  This must be what I was thinking above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's get to the basic, what does it mean for a multi-variable function to be injective?

A function is injective if $ f(p) = f(q) \implies p = q $, for multi-variable function, we just extend p and q to a pair of variables, so

$ f(x_1, y_1) = f(x_2, y_2) \implies x_1 = x_2 $ and $y_1 = y_2 $.

To prove that for our specific function, we see that if

$ 12x_1 - 8y_1 = 12x_2 - 8y_2 $

then $ 12(x_1 - x_2) = 8(y_1 - y_2) \implies 3(x_1 - x_2) = 2(y_1 - y_2) $

We have the intuition that it is better $ x_1 - x_2 $ is even, let it be 2, now obviously $ y_1 - y_2 $ has to be 3, so we come up with this pairs:
$ x_1 = 3, x_2 = 1 $
$ y_1 = 4, y_2 = 1 $

Now $ f(3, 4) = 12 \times 3 - 8 \times 4 = 4 = 12 \times 1 - 8 \times 1 = f(1, 1) $

So to your surprise! The function is **NOT** injective!

The function just surjective though.

Again, to prove that 12x - 8y is surjective, it suffice to be able to find $ (x,y) $ for all values $ v | 4 $ in the range.

Now $ v | 4 $, so we can write $ v = 4u $. Now $ f(u, u) = 12u - 8u = 4u = v $ will work!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the function $f$ is a homomorphism we can also show it is injective (a monomorphism) by showing that $\ker f \neq 0$. That is
$$f(x,y)=12x-8y=0$$
this gives us that
$$3x=2y$$
Which clearly has more than the $0$ so it's not the trivial kernel and hence not injective.